# GCC fails to compile correct code

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to compile **uClibc 0.9.33.2** for my old router with **Ubicom IP7k** processor. Since it's architecture isn't officially supported by neither GCC nor uClibc, I have to port it myself and use a modified version of GCC (`ubicom32-uclinux-gcc (GCC) 4.4.1 20100320 (stable)`) from processor's vendor. Everything was compiling fine, until GCC showed me a weird error.

```
  CC libc/sysdeps/linux/common/fstatat.os
In file included from libc/sysdeps/linux/common/xstatconv.h:26,
                 from libc/sysdeps/linux/common/fstatat.c:11:
./include/bits/kernel_stat.h:25: error: expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '__attribute__' before '.' token
./include/bits/kernel_stat.h:52: error: expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '__attribute__' before '.' token
make: *** [libc/sysdeps/linux/common/fstatat.os] Error 1
```

kernel_stat.h:

```
#ifndef _BITS_STAT_STRUCT_H
#define _BITS_STAT_STRUCT_H

#ifndef _LIBC
#error bits/kernel_stat.h is for internal uClibc use only!
#endif

/* This file provides whatever this particular arch's kernel thinks 
 * struct kernel_stat should look like...  It turns out each arch has a 
 * different opinion on the subject... */

struct kernel_stat {
    unsigned short st_dev;
    unsigned short __pad1;
    unsigned long st_ino;
    unsigned short st_mode;
    unsigned short st_nlink;
    unsigned short st_uid;
    unsigned short st_gid;
    unsigned short st_rdev;
    unsigned short __pad2;
    unsigned long  st_size;
    unsigned long  st_blksize;
    unsigned long  st_blocks;
    unsigned long  st_atime;            <-- error occurs here
    unsigned long  __unused1;
    unsigned long  st_mtime;
    unsigned long  __unused2;
    unsigned long  st_ctime;
    unsigned long  __unused3;
    unsigned long  __unused4;
    unsigned long  __unused5;
};

struct kernel_stat64 {
    unsigned char   __pad0[6];
    unsigned short  st_dev;
    unsigned char   __pad1[4];
#define _HAVE_STAT64___ST_INO
    unsigned long   __st_ino;
    unsigned int    st_mode;
    unsigned int    st_nlink;
    unsigned long   st_uid;
    unsigned long   st_gid;
    unsigned char   __pad2[6];
    unsigned short  st_rdev;
    unsigned char   __pad3[4];
    long long   st_size;
    unsigned long   st_blksize;
    unsigned long   st_blocks;  /* Number 512-byte blocks allocated. */
    unsigned long   __pad4;     /* future possible st_blocks high bits */
    unsigned long   st_atime;           <-- and here
    unsigned long   __pad5;
    unsigned long   st_mtime;
    unsigned long   __pad6;
    unsigned long   st_ctime;
    unsigned long   __pad7;     /* will be high 32 bits of ctime someday */
    unsigned long long  st_ino;
};

#endif  /*  _BITS_STAT_STRUCT_H */
```

What exactly goes wrong here and is there any way to fix it without having to update GCC?

Comment: You can take a look at the output generated by `gcc -E` to look at the actual source after pre-processing, to see if macro expansion if causing any trouble...

Comment: Macros - those things that sometimes make reasonable looking code into something completely different. Since nearly every time I see the `expected ':', ',', ';', '} ...` error it's caused by a macro problem, I wish that the diagnostic would mention macros in some why. In the meantime, I've had the association between the error and macros ingrained in my mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`st_atime`, etc. cannot be members of `struct stat`. Instead they are macros that expand to `st_atim.tv_sec`, etc. (note the lack of final `e`), and `st_atim` etc. are members with type `struct timespec`. The kernel has this wrong and just recreates the same layout flat in its notion of `struct stat` but you have to do it in a way that's correct for userspace.